# How to initialize semaphore without using semctl fourth argument union semun as it is optional?

Tags: linux

Why fourth argument of function semctl in System V implementation of semaphore is optional which is union semun, because i find it necessary to initialize the value of semaphore, by its val or array member. Is there any other way exist by which we can initialize semaphore without using fourth argument of semctl, as every where it is mentioned as optional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fourth argument is optional, because `semctl` is used to send commands. Not all commands require arguments, in which case the fourth argument can be ignored.

It can *not* be ignored with commands that require it, such as SETVAL or IPC_INFO. More information is in the documentation for this call, for example [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/semctl)